# apt-get install 実行時に発生する、KeyError: 'collectstatic'のエラーの解消方法

Tags: python, django, apt

Openstackをシングルノードで構築しています。Horizonパッケージインストール時以下のエラーが発生します。
KeyError: 'collectstatic' が発生していることが第一の原因かと思いますが、このエラーが発生する理由もわかりません。
原因、対処方法などをご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

以下は `apt-get install` の実行結果です。

```sh
root@dlp:~# sudo apt-get install -y openstack-dashboard
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
openstack-dashboard
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 33.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package openstack-dashboard.
(Reading database ... 228476 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openstack-dashboard_4%3a19.2.0-0ubuntu1~cloud0_all.deb ...
Unpacking openstack-dashboard (4:19.2.0-0ubuntu1~cloud0) ...
Setting up openstack-dashboard (4:19.2.0-0ubuntu1~cloud0) ...
Collecting and compressing static assets...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
WARNING:root:"dashboards" and "default_dashboard" in (local_)settings is DEPRECATED now and may be unsupported in some future release. The preferred way to specify the order of dashboards and the default dashboard is the pluggable dashboard mechanism (in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/enabled, /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/enabled).
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 204, in fetch_command
app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'collectstatic'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 211, in fetch_command
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 79, in getattr
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 66, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 157, in init
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 352, in <module>
STATICFILES_DIRS += settings_utils.get_xstatic_dirs(
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/utils/settings.py", line 288, in get_xstatic_dirs
module = import_module(module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'horizon.xstatic'
dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard (--configure):
installed openstack-dashboard package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
openstack-dashboard
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

(追記1)pip install実施のエラー

```sh
root@dlp:~# sudo pip install -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/stein -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openstack/horizon/stable/stein/requirements.txt
(中略)
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires dogpile.cache>=1.0.2, but you have dogpile-cache 0.7.1 which is incompatible.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires oslo.log>=3.44.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires oslo.policy>=3.6.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.3.0, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.config>=8.1.0, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.0, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.log>=4.3.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.policy>=3.7.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.3.0, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
glance 23.0.0.0b3.dev25 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires cryptography>=3.1, but you have cryptography 2.8 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires decorator>=4.4.2, but you have decorator 4.3.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires keystoneauth1>=4.2.1, but you have keystoneauth1 3.13.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.concurrency>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-concurrency 3.29.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.config>=8.3.2, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.context>=3.1.1, but you have oslo-context 2.22.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.1, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.log>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.policy>=3.6.2, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.serialization>=4.1.0, but you have oslo-serialization 2.28.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.1.1, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires oslo.utils>=4.8.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires osprofiler>=3.4.0, but you have osprofiler 2.6.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires pbr>=5.5.1, but you have pbr 5.1.3 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires pyparsing>=2.4.7, but you have pyparsing 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires python-glanceclient>=3.2.2, but you have python-glanceclient 2.16.0 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires python-keystoneclient>=4.1.1, but you have python-keystoneclient 3.19.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires python-novaclient>=17.2.1, but you have python-novaclient 13.0.2 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires python-swiftclient>=3.10.1, but you have python-swiftclient 3.7.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires pytz>=2020.1, but you have pytz 2018.9 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires requests>=2.25.1, but you have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires six>=1.15.0, but you have six 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires stevedore>=3.2.2, but you have stevedore 1.30.1 which is incompatible.
cinder 19.0.0.0b2.dev2 requires WebOb>=1.8.6, but you have webob 1.8.5 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires keystoneauth1>=3.14.0, but you have keystoneauth1 3.13.2 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires openstacksdk>=0.31.2, but you have openstacksdk 0.27.1 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires oslo.config>=8.0.0, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires oslo.log>=4.3.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires oslo.policy>=3.7.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.3.0, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
neutron 18.1.0.dev508 requires oslo.utils>=4.5.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires keystoneauth1>=3.16.0, but you have keystoneauth1 3.13.2 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires openstacksdk>=0.35.0, but you have openstacksdk 0.27.1 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires os-service-types>=1.7.0, but you have os-service-types 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.concurrency>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-concurrency 3.29.1 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.config>=8.6.0, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.context>=3.1.1, but you have oslo-context 2.22.2 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.1, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.log>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.policy>=3.7.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.serialization>=4.1.0, but you have oslo-serialization 2.28.2 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.3.0, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires oslo.utils>=4.8.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires pbr>=5.5.1, but you have pbr 5.1.3 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires python-neutronclient>=7.1.0, but you have python-neutronclient 6.12.1 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires PyYAML>=5.1, but you have pyyaml 3.13 which is incompatible.
nova 23.1.0.dev289 requires requests>=2.25.1, but you have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires oslo.log>=4.3.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires oslo.policy>=3.7.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires oslo.upgradecheck>=1.3.0, but you have oslo-upgradecheck 0.2.1 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires oslo.utils>=4.5.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
openstack-placement 5.1.0.dev27 requires requests>=2.25.0, but you have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires Django<3.0,>=2.2, but you have django 2.0.13 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires keystoneauth1>=4.3.1, but you have keystoneauth1 3.13.2 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.1, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires oslo.policy>=3.2.0, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires oslo.utils>=4.8.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires pbr>=5.5.0, but you have pbr 5.1.3 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires python-cinderclient>=8.0.0, but you have python-cinderclient 4.2.2 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires python-keystoneclient>=3.22.0, but you have python-keystoneclient 3.19.1 which is incompatible.
horizon 20.0.1.dev6 requires requests>=2.25.1, but you have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
tempest 28.0.1.dev11 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
tempest 28.0.1.dev11 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
tox 3.24.0 requires six>=1.14.0, but you have six 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
tooz 2.9.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
taskflow 4.6.1 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires cliff>=3.5.0, but you have cliff 2.14.1 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires openstacksdk>=0.53.0, but you have openstacksdk 0.27.1 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires osc-lib>=2.3.0, but you have osc-lib 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires python-keystoneclient>=3.22.0, but you have python-keystoneclient 3.19.1 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires python-novaclient>=17.0.0, but you have python-novaclient 13.0.2 which is incompatible.
python-openstackclient 5.5.0 requires stevedore>=2.0.1, but you have stevedore 1.30.1 which is incompatible.
pypowervm 1.1.26 requires pytz>=2019.3, but you have pytz 2018.9 which is incompatible.
pypowervm 1.1.26 requires six>=1.14.0, but you have six 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
oslo-versionedobjects 2.4.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
oslo-privsep 2.6.0 requires cffi>=1.14.0, but you have cffi 1.12.2 which is incompatible.
oslo-limit 1.4.0 requires openstacksdk>=0.31.1, but you have openstacksdk 0.27.1 which is incompatible.
oslo-limit 1.4.0 requires oslo.log>=3.44.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
oslo-cache 2.8.1 requires dogpile.cache>=1.1.2, but you have dogpile-cache 0.7.1 which is incompatible.
oslo-cache 2.8.1 requires oslo.config>=8.1.0, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
oslo-cache 2.8.1 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.0, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
oslo-cache 2.8.1 requires oslo.log>=4.2.1, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
oslo-cache 2.8.1 requires oslo.utils>=4.2.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
os-win 5.4.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.concurrency>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-concurrency 3.29.1 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.context>=3.1.1, but you have oslo-context 2.22.2 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.i18n>=5.0.1, but you have oslo-i18n 3.23.1 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.log>=4.4.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.serialization>=4.1.0, but you have oslo-serialization 2.28.2 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.8.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires pbr>=5.5.1, but you have pbr 5.1.3 which is incompatible.
os-brick 4.4.0 requires requests>=2.25.1, but you have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
neutron-lib 2.12.0 requires keystoneauth1>=3.14.0, but you have keystoneauth1 3.13.2 which is incompatible.
neutron-lib 2.12.0 requires oslo.config>=8.0.0, but you have oslo-config 6.8.2 which is incompatible.
neutron-lib 2.12.0 requires oslo.log>=4.3.0, but you have oslo-log 3.42.5 which is incompatible.
neutron-lib 2.12.0 requires oslo.policy>=3.6.2, but you have oslo-policy 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
neutron-lib 2.12.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.5.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
keystonemiddleware 9.3.0 requires python-keystoneclient>=3.20.0, but you have python-keystoneclient 3.19.1 which is incompatible.
httplib2 0.19.1 requires pyparsing<3,>=2.4.2, but you have pyparsing 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
google-api-python-client 2.14.0 requires six<2dev,>=1.13.0, but you have six 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
google-api-core 1.31.0 requires six>=1.13.0, but you have six 1.12.0 which is incompatible.
glance-store 2.6.0 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
glance-store 2.6.0 requires oslo.utils>=4.7.0, but you have oslo-utils 3.40.7 which is incompatible.
enmerkar 0.7.1 requires django>=2.2, but you have django 2.0.13 which is incompatible.
botocore 1.21.6 requires urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4, but you have urllib3 1.24.1 which is incompatibl
Successfully installed Babel-2.6.0 Django-2.0.13 Pint-0.9 PyYAML-3.13 WebOb-1.8.5 XStatic-Angular-Bootstrap-2.
(後略)
```

Comment: バグとして登録されていますが、公式の対応はまだ為されていない模様ですね。[Bug #1860894 "openstack-dashboard failed to install because of collectstatic not found" : Bugs : horizon package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/horizon/+bug/1860894)

Comment: 紹介されている方法で依存関係を修復してみましたが、以下の通りエラーが発生しています。全般的に現環境のOpenstackのバージョンが古いのかもしれません。一括でアップデートするような方法はありませんでしょうか？
KeyError: 'collectstatic'は消えました。
---
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires dogpile.cache>=1.0.2, but you have dogpile-cache 0.7.1 which is incompatible.
keystone 19.1.0.dev15 requires jsonschema>=3.2.0, but you have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
:

Comment: エラーの内容を質問文の方へ追記してもらえますか？

Comment: エラー内容を追記いたしました。